# Off Canvas Sidebar That Pushes Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Is it possible to have a side navigation menu transition in from the left whilst pushing other content along with an opaque colour overlay?

Versions that I've tried to do work perfectly in browsers on desktop, but when I switch to mobile, the sidebar extends the height of the page and the page loses its flow.

Example: *updated* https://www.codeply.com/p/RRVDkqEyj4 - when I view the page through Codeply on a mobile device, it works perfectly. However, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62pFb.jpg) is how the left menu displays on mobile devices **only** when it is uploaded to my website. Also, if I make the left menu transition in from the right-hand side, that also works perfectly and the menu doesn't scale larger... It's just something to do with it transitioning in from the left.

Edit: Codeply link has updated code.

Edit: [My issue has now been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046219/transform-translatex-positive-value-causes-scroll-bug-on-mobile-window-resize#comment104335158_59046219).

Comment: Could you post relevant code, or even better a working example ?

Comment: Updated my question with an example :)

Comment: Have you added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your page ?

Comment: Yeah, my tag is as follows: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

Comment: can you provide a link to your site which exhibits the problem ?

Comment: keep in mind that the issue appears at codeply as well and even in desktop browsers if you resize the browser so it has vertical scrolling and you scroll to the bottom before opening the left menu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are applying a transformation to the `#mainWrapper` (*`translateX(80%)`*) and that affects the `position:fixed` elements inside it as well.

You could either re-style you whole page to make sure the `#mainWrapper` element reaches all the way to the bottom of the page, or you could move the overlays outside of the `#mainWrapper`.

---

Just moving the two overlays outsite

change

```
<div class="main-wrapper" id="mainWrapper" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
    <div class="service-menu-overlay" id="serviceMenuOverlay" onClick="closeServices()"></div>
    <div class="burger-menu-overlay" id="burgerMenuOverlay" onClick="closeBurger()"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="service-menu-overlay" id="serviceMenuOverlay" onClick="closeServices()"></div>
<div class="burger-menu-overlay" id="burgerMenuOverlay" onClick="closeBurger()"></div>

<div class="main-wrapper" id="mainWrapper" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
```

and

```
.service-menu-overlay.overlay-show{z-index: 5000 !important;}
```

to

```
.service-menu-overlay.overlay-show{z-index: 1 !important;}
```

should fix most problems.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sort of example so I can further understand how to accomplish it? I fully understand what you mean but no matter what I try it just does not work... 
I've got it to work with the top navigation menu being static, but I need it to be fixed to the top at all times.

Comment: @meh1710 added update to answer with some code changes